# Change column value if date is older than 1 hour in mysql/mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Say I have below SQL table:

```
+------------+---------------------+
|  Status    |   Date              |
 ------------+---------------------+
|  Available | 2020-12-19 18:03:42 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Basically I want MySQL to check the Date column every 3 minutes and if Date value is older than 1 hour, I want to change `Status` to `Offline`. Can we achieve such thing in SQL? Alternatively if there is easier solution in Django python, I am open to use that as well.

Comment: I think you should look at creating a Stored Procedure and then scheduling it to run every 3 minutes , if you want to do it via My SQL.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select (case when date + interval 1 hour < current_timestamp then 'Offline'
                 else status
            end) as status,
           . . .   -- whatever other columns you have here
    from t;
```

A view has the following advantages:

- The value is automatically correct.  Users of the view will see the `'Offline'` status exactly after an hour.
- There is no overhead on changing the data.
- This works even if the entire system goes down and then comes back up.

You can actually set the status at your leisure -- say a job that runs once per day or per week at an off-time.

Comment: I laterly copy pasted you query except `t` to my table, but the status value never changes, even thought the Date value is `2020-12-18 19:40:33`

Comment: oh lastly i can `select * from v_t` to view the status. Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check and update the status in a single statement:

```
update mytable set status = 'Offline'
where date < current_timestamp - interval 1 hour;
```

Now we need to schedule the query to execute on a regular basis. For this, one would typically use [MySQL's event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html):

```
create event event_update_status
on schedule every 3 minute
starts current_timestamp
ends current_timestamp + interval 1 day
do
    update mytable set status = 'Offline'
    where date < current_timestamp - interval 1 hour;
```

Comment: it works if I execute `update` directly, but doesn't seem to be working on even scheduler

Comment: @MorariJan: what happens when you run the `create event` statement?